I don't know why LITEXP1[1:] -= LITEXP1[0] will work on a list sometimes
I found something really confusing. When I am running this python code, it worked with no error.
LITEXP1 = np.array([333.7, 375.6])  
LITEXP1 = [value * 0.123983 for value in LITEXP1]  
LITEXP1 = sorted(LITEXP1) 
LITEXP1[1:] -= LITEXP1[0]

The last line shouldn't work, It should result in a TypeError. But it worked in my program. Just copy it to a new python file and you could see it running.
But I can still get this kind of problem with TypeError randomly in my project when I'm doing something likeLITEXP1[1:] -= LITEXP1[0].
I understand I should convert them all to numpy arrays, but why this will happen? Is it mentioned somewhere in the document?

When you say "it worked", what did it do?

It just subtracts all items from 1 to the end by the 0th element in the list, without TypeError.

Yes it does, so I don't understand your problem. If you define LITEXP1 = [333.7, 375.6] it won't work. Obviously the type <class 'numpy.float64'> can handle this.

I think when we execute the second and third line, it should convert LITEXP1 to a list. We should get a TypeError when executing the last line.

Why do you think it should return a TypeError.  Numpy does "broadcasting".  If you perform an operation between a scalar and a numpy array, it pretends that the scalar is actually an array the same size as the other array with every value being the scalar.

@FrankYellin But LITEXP1 is a list, not a numpy array.

Because after list comprehension and sorted, LITEXP1 should be a list, not a NumPy array when we reach the fourth line.

list vs array isn't the issue; float vs numpy.float64 is (which was @Matthias' point).

@ScottHunter Why is that relevant? LITEXP1[1:] returns a list slice, which is a list.

@Barmar: Seems you (literally) answered your own question. :)

This is happening because the elements of LITEXP1 are np.float64 values.
Since there's no list.__isub__() method,
LITEXP1[1:] -= LITEXP1[0]

is treated as
LITEXP1[1:] = LITEXP[1:] - LITEXP1[0]

Then, since there's no list.__sub__() method, this uses the np.float64.__rsub__() method, so it's equivalent to
LITEXP1[1:] = LITEXP1[0].__rsub__(LITEXP1[1:])

This makes use of numpy's automatic broadcasting with any array-like value, it subtracts LITEXP1[0] from each element of LITEXP1[1:].
Then slice assignment is used to replace the corresponding elements in LITEXP1.

Thank you so much! It was very helpful. Could you recommend some resources or books for me to learn more about this?

I think now I should edit my code to make things like LITEXP1 stay a NumPy array throughout the entire program.

Python data model describes how Python translates operators into method calls. Applying the rules step by step will lead to the above solution.
